# Creating hand drawn like illustrations

Tags: illustration

I am new to UX and want to start creating illustrations for modern websites. Please help me have a check list to prepare my self to be able to create illustrations like the below.

What are the requirements, what's the best software to use, any courses that can be suggested and any tips for a beginner? I am currently doing a course for basic hand drawing because I have imagined I would need the drawing skill. Thank you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for notifying about duplicate answer. I don't know how it happened.

Comment: @Vikas - yeah it's happened to me a few times before when editing a question. Annoying.

Comment: To the OP, I think this is a very broad question, and the examples you posted could be made using a variety of software.  There's no way to tell for sure which software was used.  Maybe look up raster image editing software, and vector image editing software. Most graphics software falls into either of those two categories, and some of your examples mix both raster and vector elements.

Comment: @BillyKerr elephant one is i guess a photo.

Comment: **No one** online, no matter how well-intentioned, can teach you or tell you the "best" method *for you to learn* how to create freeform or conceptual art.  If anything, it really takes direct, face-to-face, instruction if you feel you need teaching at all. One *can* be taught technical aspects of reproduction online, but the conceptual stuff.. nope.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Photoshop or Illustrator subscription, you can try any of them. I know about them so I'll let you know about them. There are free software too, but I don't know them much.

I'm not very experienced, but still I'll share my own experience.

---

Usually, I find it easy in a vector software like Illustrator to do such illustrations (last 3 images). You have lot of flexibilities and brushes options. I do all my illustrations in Illustrator.

But that doesn't mean you can't use Photoshop for it. I've seen many good artists using Photoshop and create really nice illustrations with textures. It's just that people get used to it or prefer one over other for some other reasons.

Basically, you'll need to work with paths, strokes and a few texture brushes and colors. There are sometimes free brushes available online. You can create your own textures in both software.

If you use Illustrator, you'll have a good benefit that you can export it at different dimensions for multiple usage.

Since Photoshop is raster based, you'll have an upper limit. If you will create something in 1080x1080 dimensions, you cant export any bigger image than this. So you'll always want to work with a bigger document size.

I often find the color part a bit hard. So if you're a beginner, I'll recommend experiment with different color profiles and see what works best for your illustrations.

---

Now another thing is, things are changing. Many people I know use a graphic tablet and pen. I'm used to with Mouse and find it comfortable. So you'll have to see what input device works best for you.

---

Did you mean drawing on paper with a medium when you said hand drawing? If yes,  it will be very helpful for you. You'll find it easy to work on shapes and paths and curves. Further, you can use your drawing skill and create some textures with different mediums like pencils or charcoal and later scan them and create brushes with them. It may seem a bit advanced, but you can always search more about it.

Even if you don't mean drawing on paper, drawing skill is always helpful for similar reasons stated above. What I want to say is it's going to help you anyway. I've seen some illustrators are good in hand drawing too. Both are form of art with many similarities.

One important thing is, it will also depend if you could apply your drawing skills in graphic illustrations effectively. For example, I'm quite good with pencil drawing, but I haven't used it my graphic illustrations. It somehow helps, but I haven't explored it. If both skills can be combined, it's always going to help you create kind of "unique" art.

Handsome Frank is an illustration agency and I really love the illustrations. You may want to have a look. If you will Google it, you can easily find it. One of the tips is to observe the work you love.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this; It helped